# Which RE tool is missing?

Tags: malware, tools, static-analysis

I am analyzing a malware at the moment which scans for a lot of filenames and ClassNames to recognize if it is under supervision or not.

My problem is, that all the filenames and ClassNames are stored as Hashes. Therefore i did some kind of dictionary attack (with a list of tools **I** know). It was very effective - but out of 20 hashes, i am still missing **one**!

I am searching for days now... it drives me crazy :D

- The hashed ClassName is: 0x56151B4F
- The hashing algorithm is: https://repl.it/repls/MaroonIrritatingAchillestang
- My list of tools (dict) is: 
  https://gist.github.com/atar-axis/b3e16ccf75852f7cb59a7e169be230b1

As you can see, there are some tools missing in my list - can you complete it?
**Please think of your most favourite tools and take a look at the list - are they already in there? :)**

Thank you very much in advance!

In case you need a list like this one day, feel free to use it.

Comment: If your current tools worked for 95%, chances are that that word is just not in your dictionary.

Comment: I added every tool to the list I ever used, then i looked up the ClassName of each and hashed it using the Algorithm above. Finally I compared the hashes to the list of hashes i extracted from the malware.

Therefore yes, this last tool it is not in the list - that's exactly the problem since I do not know any more RE tools for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a Z3 solver if simple bruteforcing fails. The hashing function doesn't seem that hard at the first glance. Of course there aren't any pre-made tools (I think) and a minimal use of your gray matter is required.

https://www.google.com.au/search?q=z3+solver+hash

Comment: You can find a lot of material about using Z3 for reverse-engineering here: [Yurichev's Blog](https://yurichev.com/blog/). Quite interesting tool, indeed.

Comment: Vitaly, the problem is that Z3 might find whatever that creates that hash. I really doubt that the hash is cryptographically safe, thus, there will be a gazillion or more collisions.

Comment: thanks! but yes, i had around 3000 collisions per hash within the first 12 hours of brute-forcing. anyway, thank you for the hint!

Comment: @joxeankoret I do not see a problem in collisions - find your gazillion and filter out the only (hopefully) valid one via some simple tool that checks for valid names. Extremely easy in Windows with blah.exe/dll/… name structure, and in Unices just look for alphanumeric space. This is a basic approach in "cryptanalysis". OP if you already have your collisions, then you're already half done, not need for Z3.